# EventToCommand Make parameter up-to-date

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I use EventToCommand and want CommandParameter binding to be updated every time event is fired. Are there any ways to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Like this PassEventArgsToCommand="True" this will pass the values to the viewmodel

**public void StartOdoMeter(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs arg)**

in arg u can get the value from that control